# Count all checkboxes in ms-access form...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to count all the checkboxes that are checked in my ms-access form.  I want that total number to be displayed on the form itself.  Here is expression I'm using;

=Count(Iif(Nz([Final Comment C1],0) = -1, 1, null))

What am I doing wrong?!?!  Thanks!

-T

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to use Sum:

```
=Sum(Iif(Nz([Final Comment C1],False), 1, 0))
```

or even

```
=-Sum([Final Comment C1])
```

in case if `[Final Comment C1]` is Yes/No data type